# Perplexing ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE when using Oracle's Analytic Functions

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

When I create this view and query the results, an ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE is received.

```
create or replace view test as
with
   wData as --Create a record set
      (
      select trunc(sysdate - 2) as transaction_date, 1 as transaction_amount from dual union all
      select trunc(sysdate - 1) as transaction_date, 2 as transaction_amount from dual union all
      select trunc(sysdate - 0) as transaction_date, 3 as transaction_amount from dual
      ),
   wTransactions as --Use an analytic function to calculate first record and assign to each record
      (
      select min(a.transaction_date) over (partition by null order by null) as first_transaction_date,
             a.transaction_date,
             a.transaction_amount
      from   wData a
      ),
   wTotals as --Sum the amounts
      (
      select a.*,
           --cast( ( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date ) as number(38,2) )     as total_days, --ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
           --cast( ( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date ) as number(38,2) ) / 2 as total_days, --ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
           --cast( ( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date ) as date )             as total_days, --ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got DATE JULIAN
                   ( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date )                   / 2 as total_days, --ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
           --      ( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date )                       as total_days, --works
           --
             sum(a.transaction_amount) over(partition by null order by null) as total_transaction_amount --commenting this statement out removes the error
           --0 / 1                                                           as total_transaction_amount --works
      from   wTransactions a
      )
select a.first_transaction_date,
       a.total_days,
       a.transaction_date,
       a.transaction_amount,
       a.total_transaction_amount
from wTotals a;

desc test

select a.first_transaction_date, a.total_transaction_amount from test a; --works
select a.first_transaction_date                             from test a; --works
select                           a.total_transaction_amount from test a; --ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

SQL> desc test
Name                     Null? Type   
------------------------ ----- ------ 
FIRST_TRANSACTION_DATE         DATE   
TOTAL_DAYS                     NUMBER 
TRANSACTION_DATE               DATE   
TRANSACTION_AMOUNT             NUMBER 
TOTAL_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT       NUMBER
```

I tried isolating the issue to the total_days field, but to no avail.
After describing the view, the data types seem to be correct.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is working fine on dbfiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/qkGQqNGW

Comment: It appears to be an issue with Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by issuing a to_char function: to_char( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date )                   / 2 as total_days,

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an issue with Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 18.3.0.0.0

[image]

I wrapped the offending statement with to_char:

```
create or replace view test as
with
   wData as --Create a record set
      (
      select trunc(sysdate - 2) as transaction_date, 1 as transaction_amount from dual union all
      select trunc(sysdate - 1) as transaction_date, 2 as transaction_amount from dual union all
      select trunc(sysdate - 0) as transaction_date, 3 as transaction_amount from dual
      ),
   wTransactions as --Use an analytic function to calculate first record and assign to each record
      (
      select min(a.transaction_date) over (partition by null order by null) as first_transaction_date,
             a.transaction_date,
             a.transaction_amount
      from   wData a
      ),
   wTotals as --Sum the amounts
      (
      select a.*,
           --cast( ( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date ) as number(38,2) )     as total_days, --ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
           --cast( ( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date ) as number(38,2) ) / 2 as total_days, --ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
           --cast( ( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date ) as date )             as total_days, --ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got DATE JULIAN
             --     ( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date )                  / 2 as total_days, --ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
             to_char( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date )                  / 2 as total_days, --ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
           --       ( trunc(sysdate) - a.first_transaction_date )                      as total_days, --works
           --
             sum(a.transaction_amount) over(partition by null order by null) as total_transaction_amount --commenting this statement out removes the error
           --0 / 1                                                           as total_transaction_amount --works
      from   wTransactions a
      )
select a.first_transaction_date,
       a.total_days,
       a.transaction_date,
       a.transaction_amount,
       a.total_transaction_amount
from wTotals a;
```